# Firebase Cloud Async Error(Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, async.js

Firstly, thanks in advance for taking your time to read this.

I've been working on a cloud function for my Firebase app and have been encountering some frustrating situations. Half of the time, my function works as expected; I see all expected logs and the DB gets updated correctly. The other half of the time, the function almost seems to stop midway through; only some of the logs appear, and only half of the expected DB updates are made. I've been debugging this for quite a while and am running out of ideas.

One thing that I've been seeing consistently in the logs is the following error:

```
Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value
```

I'm not sure if this error is what's causing the inconsistencies noted above, but it's the only lead I have at the moment. At this point, I've commented out nearly all the code in my cloud function and the error seems to be caused by the use of an [`async.auto`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) function. As soon as I remove any reference to [`async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async), the error goes away.

To summarize my questions:
1 - Why is the use of [`async.auto`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) causing the above error?
2 - Is the error the reason that there are inconsistencies with the outcome of running my cloud function?

For reference, here is my now overly-simplified and pointless function that throws the above error:

```
exports.updateLeaderboard = functions.database.ref('/contests/{dateString}/ladder/dayIsComplete').onWrite((event, context) => {
    const isComplete = event.after._data,
        contestType = 'ladder',
        dateString = context.params.dateString;

    if (isComplete !== true) {
        console.warn(`${contestType} for ${dateString} is not yet complete.`);

        return false;
    }

    async.auto({
        fetchWinningPicks: cb => {
            return cb();
        },

        // ... Other stuff that I've now commented out

    }, err => {
        if (err) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: The error message is saying that you aren't returning a promise (from the top-level function) that resolves when all the async work is complete.  And you're definitely not doing that.  I don't know what this async package is supposed to do for you, but if it doesn't somehow yield a promise, it's not likely to work out for you.  Read up on the docs for terminating functions for more information.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Comment: I appreciate the quick reply, @DougStevenson. I guess I had convinced myself that `async.js` returned a promise, but clearly that isn't the case. I was able to resolve the error by wrapping my `async.auto` flow in a `new Promise()` and resolving/rejecting in my final callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the error by wrapping my `async.auto` flow in a `new Promise()` and resolving/rejecting in my final callback:

```
exports.updateLeaderboard = functions.database.ref('/contests/{dateString}/ladder/dayIsComplete').onWrite((event, context) => {
    const isComplete = event.after._data,
        contestType = 'ladder',
        dateString = context.params.dateString;

    if (isComplete !== true) {
        console.warn(`${contestType} for ${dateString} is not yet complete.`);

        return false;
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        async.auto({
            fetchWinningPicks: cb => {
                return cb();
            },

            // ... Other stuff that I've now commented out

        }, err => {
            if (err) {
                reject();
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
};
```

This appears to fix both of my issues above.